# Cómo contar la cantidad de id duplicados en una tabla y mostrarla en un gráfico?

Tags: django

estoy contando la cantidad de id duplicados en una tabla en django y mostrandolo en un grafico, hay una mejor solucion?

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
    osde=models.ForeignKey(Osde, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    software=models.ForeignKey(Software, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    entidad=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vencimiento_licencia=models.DateField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
siglas_osde = Osde.objects.all()
osde1 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=1).count()
osde2 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=2).count()
osde3 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=3).count()
osde4 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=4).count()
osde5 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=5).count()
osde6 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=6).count()
osde7 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=7).count()
osde8 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=8).count()
osde9 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=9).count()
osde10 = Contrato.objects.filter(osde_id=10).count()
data['x_osde'] = [x.siglas_osde for x in siglas_osde]
data['y_osde'] = [osde1, osde2, osde3, osde4, osde5, osde6, osde7, osde8, osde9, osde10]
```

Todo eso se me muestra en un grafico pero:
Lo que quiero es si se puede mejorar ese codigo en mi vista, porque si se trata de mas informacion, tener que repetir todas esas lineas de codigo.

Saludos